# jsf page refresh maintenance

Tags: jsf-2, navigation

I new to jsf and using user custom authentication and navigating through pages. When i submit a form i am going to next page but when i user browser refresh on second page it take me back to the form submission page instead of same page.

my first page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
    <h:head>
        <title>Community</title>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form id="login">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <rich:panel> 
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Login form" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="210">
                        <h:outputText value="Username:" />
                        <h:inputText label="username" id="username" value="#{loginMB.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="user name is requried">
                            <f:validateLength minimum="5" />
                        </h:inputText>                    

                        <h:outputText value="Password" />
                        <h:inputSecret label="password" id="password" value="#{loginMB.password}" requiredMessage="password is requried">
                            <f:validateLength minimum="8" maximum="16"  />
                        </h:inputSecret>
                        <rich:notifyMessages  stayTime="2000" nonblocking="true"  />

                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <a4j:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginMB.outcome.toString()}" actionListener="#{loginMB.authUser()}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </rich:panel>

            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

My backing bean

```
package com.jsf;

import com.ejb.UsersFacadeLocal;
import com.entity.Users;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author krishna teja
 */
@Named(value = "loginMB")
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginMB implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<String, Object> sessionMap;
    private ExternalContext externalContext;

    @EJB
    private UsersFacadeLocal usersFacade;
    protected Users user;
    protected List<Users> lusers;
    protected String username;
    protected String password;
    protected String role;
    protected boolean islogedin;
    protected String outcome = "";

    public LoginMB() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (this.usersFacade.findAll() != null) {
            this.lusers = this.usersFacade.findAll();
        }
    }

    public void authUser() {
        FacesMessage message = null;
        this.user = usersFacade.findByUserName(this.username);
        if (null != user) {
            if (this.username.equals(this.user.getUsername()) && this.password.equals(this.user.getPassword())) {
                this.islogedin = true;
                externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
                sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
                sessionMap.put(username, user);
                this.outcome = "user";
                System.out.println(this.sessionMap.isEmpty()+"  trying to print user");
                if ("Admin".equals(this.username)) {
                    this.outcome = "admin";
                }
            }
        } else {
            message = new FacesMessage("The user name provided is registered please register if u are new user");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(username, message);
        }
    }

    public void verifyUseLogin(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
        if (!this.islogedin) {
            doRedirect();
        }
    }

    private void doRedirect() {
        try {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void logout() {
        this.password = null;
        this.username = null;
        this.sessionMap.clear();
        try{
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        session.invalidate();
        }catch(IllegalStateException e){
            System.out.println("exception closing on already closed session");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        doRedirect();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Users> getLusers() {
        return lusers;
    }

    public void setLusers(List<Users> lusers) {
        this.lusers = lusers;
    }

    public String getOutcome() {
        return outcome;
    }

    public void setOutcome(String outcome) {
        this.outcome = outcome;
    }
}
```

My navigated page after submission page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <h:head>
        <title>this is admin page</title>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event listener="#{loginMB.verifyUseLogin(event)}" type="preRenderView">
    </f:event>
    </f:metadata>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        this is admin side page for test

    </h:body>   
</html>
```

faces context

```
<faces-config version="2.1"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>user</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/user.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>admin</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/admin.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>register</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/register.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

i want to go to the same page after browser refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `<redirect/>` in your `navigation-case`, e.g.:

```
<navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>admin</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/admin.xhtml</to-view-id>
  <redirect/>
</navigation-case>
```